# Websockets - pass data outside of onmessage()

Tags: javascript, websocket, firefox-addon-webextensions

My WebExtension connects to a WebSockets server to retrieve data.

```
function foo(responseDetails){
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9876/");

    ws.onopen = function(event){
        // send some data to the server
        ws.send("some data");
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(event){
        // receive some data from the server
        data = event.data;
    }

    // how to access the data from here?
    if(data == 0)
        return {cancel:true}
    else
        return {cancel:false}
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        foo, 
        {urls:["*//*/*"]},
        ["blocking"]
)
```

Whenever a request is completed, function `foo()` is called which opens a WebSocket to `ws://localhost:9876`, sends a string, then receives `data`. The data determines whether or not the request will be blocked.

After reading through [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron), I'm still confused. I'm not sure how to implement the callback while within function `foo()`.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514155/javascript-websocket-onmessage-event-data) but the answer is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use promises for this exact use-case, something as follows should work:

```
function foo(responseDetails) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9876/");

    ws.onopen = function(event) {
      // send some data to the server
      ws.send("some data");
    }

    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
      // receive some data from the server
      var data = event.data;
      if (data == 0) {
        resolve({
          cancel: true
        });
      } else {
        resolve({
          cancel: false
        })
      }
    }
  });
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  foo, {
    urls: ["*//*/*"]
  }, ["blocking"]
)
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest)

Comment: There's a syntax error at line 24. I tried rewriting the code, to no luck. Still happens on line 24 https://pastebin.com/LY8epTAQ

Comment: Where would I put the WebSocket definition `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9876")`?